# Using cylindrical coordinates compute $\int_B z\, dx\, dy \,dz$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral, cylindrical-coordinates

Using cylindrical coordinates compute $\int_B z \,dx \,dy \,dz$ where $B$ satisfies $1 \le z \le 2, x^2+y^2 \le 1$

My workings out:

I get the following for the integral $$\int_1^2z\,dz\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta\int_0^1r\,dr$$

I used the fact that $r^2 = x^2+y^2 \le 1 \implies r \le1$

Now this gives me the right answer, however I took a guess at the limits for $\theta$ so I was hoping for an explanation as to why its from $0 \le \theta \le 2\pi$ as I had thought it was from $0 \le \theta \le \frac{\pi}{2}$. Given that both values for $z$ and $r$ were positive.

Comment: The quesiton should be solved without any coordinate change: For each $z$, the cross section of the domain is just a disc with radius $1$, hence the integral of  $zdxdy$ is just $\pi z$, and we simply integrate $\int_1^2 \pi z dz$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$, if you only take $\theta\in\left[0,\frac\pi2\right]$, then you will not get every pair $(x,y)$; you will only get those $(x,y)$ such that $x,y\geqslant0$. Since that cylinder has points all around the $z$-axis, you have to take $\theta\in[0,2\pi]$ or in any other closed interval whose length is $2\pi$.

Comment: May I ask; What gives the impression that the 'cylinder has points all around the z-axis'? For example, what should I look out for to not make the misjudgement for $\theta$? Is this information already given in the inequalities provided?

Comment: The $z$-axis is an axis of rotation of the cylinder. In other words, the cylinder has rotationL symmetry with respect to it. What else is needed?

Comment: Could you confirm for me that given this particular question, assumably as a triple integral we would actually get for $x$ this $\int_{-1}^1$ which would explain why there is a full rotation. I think I'm confused on interpreting the $z-axis$, I had assumed if the $z-axis$ was between two positive bounds then $\theta$ would also be positive. But after looking at the polar coordinates given by $x^2+y^2 \le 1$ I come to my first judgement. So the limits of the $z-axis$ do not control the cycle of $\theta$?

Comment: I cannot confirm what you want me to confirm since I have no idea about the meaning of “we would actually get for $x$ this $\int_{-1}^1$”. And the $z$-axis is the line $\{(0,0,z)\mid z\in\Bbb R\}$, which, by the way, is unbounded. When you talk about the $z$-axis being “between two positive bounds”, my guess is that you are talking about that, when $(x,y,z)\in B$, then $1\leqslant z\leqslant2$. That has no relation whatsoever with the choice of values for $\theta$. If, say, $-\pi\leqslant z\leqslant10^e$, we would still have $0\leqslant\theta\leqslant2\pi$.

Comment: I think that I better understand this now. I will start to visualise $z$ and $\theta$ independent during the calculation process for the bounds.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.